# How do Slice a string into pairs

Tags: ruby, arrays, split

For the project I am doing, I need to make pairs out of the input, but I can't figure out how, I could use some help.
How it is:

```
2209222717080109
```

How I want it to become:

```
["22","09","22","27","17","08","01","09"]
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Thanks, and I must have missed it sorry

Comment: He probably needs just the consecutive slices, not all possible combinations, in which case `each_slice` is a better approach.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm not in a rush but it helped me get what I wanted so i tought it was The Answer

Comment: SO newbies are often quick to make a selection, possibly to show their appreciation, but it can have some negative consequences. In particular, it may discourage users from posting other, possibly better answers, and it's not very courteous to those still preparing answers when the green checkmark flashes on after only a few minutes.  I suggest waiting at least a couple of hours before making a selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input = "2209222717080109"
input.chars.each_slice(2).map(&:join)
["22", "09", "22", "27", "17", "08", "01", "09"]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
"2209222717080109".scan /../
  #=> ["22", "09", "22", "27", "17", "08", "01", "09"]
```

Comment: Ahh!.. You came up with the same before me.. Hehehehe :)

Comment: @Arup, by a few seconds only...(see the link in the comment I left).

Answer (score 2):

[Convert it to a string](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s), [convert that into an array of characters](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chars), then take [each consecutive slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) of two characters, and [join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join) [each of those slices](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) together:

```
2209222717080109.to_s.chars.each_slice(2).map(&:join)
#=> ["22", "09", "22", "27", "17", "08", "01", "09"]
```